# What kind of distribution is this? Use Moment Generating functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X  Pois($\phi$) and Y Pois($\tau$) be independent poisson random variables.
a) Use moment generating functions to show that Z = X + Y  Pois($\phi +\tau$ )
b) Find the conditional distribution of X given Z = n.

I know what moment generating functions are for Poisson distribution, $e^{\lambda(e^t-1) }.$ Therefore I was able to figure out that for $Z=X+Y~Pois(\phi+\tau)$ Take the moment generating parts and multiply them together.

However, How do I solve part b? Bruce Trumbo below suggests to use basic conditional probabilities, but I can not think of a way to do it. I may have found the answer here though: http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~fribergh/homework2.pdf. This is not mine nor was it assigned to me

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is this from? The "dim" looks like a typo to me.

Comment: It's possible.  Maybe someone mistyped $\backslash$sim.

Comment: it was an error. It has been fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree from context that this problem can only be asking about
the sum of independent Poisson random variables:

If $X \sim Pois(\phi)$, and independently $Y \sim Pois(\tau),$
then use MGFs to show that $Z = X + Y \sim Pois(\phi + \tau).$

In these circumstances, the distribution of the sum of two
random variables can be found by taking the product of their
MGFs. Simplify the product and you will see the MGF of another
Poisson. Then use the fact that only one distribution can
have a given MGF.

For an intuitive insight into this result consider the following
example. Radioactive decay of relatively stable radioactive
elements is well modeled by a Poisson random variable:
Suppose you have two clay-like chunks of radioactive uranium ore. Chunk
A emits $X \sim Pois(\phi)$ particles into your Geiger counter
each minute and chunk B emits $Y \sim Pois(\tau)$ particles per minute.
If you mold the two chunks of ore together, then they will
emit an average of $\phi + \tau$ per minute, and there is no
reason to believe the distribution of particles from the new combined chunk could
be anything but Poisson distributed.

I believe that both this and your second question are already essentially answered on this 
site. Search for 162839. However, Part (a) does not use MGFs. In case you want to try part (b) on your own first, I will say that it is not most easily answered with MGFs
but by writing out the conditional probability and simplifying.
The result is binomial.

Comment: Thank you for the first part. But how would I write out the conditional probability part like this: $P(X|Z)=p(XZ)/p(Z)$? How would I find the $p(XZ)$ part then?